# Accessing full url of 'View in browser' link in document library

Tags: document-library, ecb-menu, custom-action

I'm trying to get the url of the 'view in browser' link that appears in the context menu for a document in the document library.

I have a custom command on the menu that I have created which calls a jscript function and I want to pass the url to it.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.